# Search and compare an array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Just need a little help here about arrays. I need to compare the array ID in the database result. If existed in the array. The database result will be overwritten based on the corresponding ID of the array

Example if we have this array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
       [company_id] => 1,
       [new_lat] => 015244,
       [new_long] => 012991
    ),
    [1] => Array(
       [company_id] => 2,
       [new_lat] => 475421,
       [new_long] => 021413
    ),

    [2] => Array(
       [company_id] => 3,
       [new_lat] => 454544,
       [new_long] => 122513
    )
)
```

I have this code for assigning values.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $companies_count; $i++) :

$company = $companies[$i];
$company_id = $company['company_id']; //this is the ID from the database result

/********These files are from array but I don't know how to search an ID in the array if existing*********/
//file information from textfile
//$file_id = $addresses_file[$i]['company_id'];
//$file_latitude = $addresses_file[$i]['new_lat'];
//$file_longitude = $addresses_file[$i]['new_long'];

//This is the assigning part. If found in the array use the array information instead of the database information
if($company_id == $file_id){
    //if found, get information from textfile
    $lat = $file_latitude;
    $long = $file_longitude;
    //echo "found";

}else{
    //if not found in then textfile get database info instead
    //echo "not found";
    $lat = $additionals[$company_id]['geo_lat'];
    $long = $additionals[$company_id]['geo_long'];

}
```

Another example supposed that we have this in the database:

```
company_id: 1
new_lat: 454451
new_long: 11211

company_id: 2
new_lat: 232332
new_long: 324343

company_id: 3
new_lat: 34232
new_long: 74874

company_id: 4
new_lat: 34434
new_long: 34344
```

Now in our array we have this:

```
company_id: 1
new_lat: 222222
new_long: 11211

company_id: 2
new_lat: 454451
new_long: 11211
```

So the final array should be

```
company_id: 1
new_lat: 222222
new_long: 11211

company_id: 2
new_lat: 454451
new_long: 11211

company_id: 3
new_lat: 34232
new_long: 74874

company_id: 4
new_lat: 34434
new_long: 34344
```

As you can see company_id 1 and 2 are overwritten.
How can I do that guys?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have this code. All i need to do is perform another loop inside the main loop and use an if statement for comparing:

```
$addresses_file = unserialize(file_get_contents('addresses.txt'));




                    for ($i = 0; $i <= $companies_count; $i++) :

                        $company = $companies[$i];
                        $company_id = $company['company_id'];

                        //file information from textfile
                        $file_id = $addresses_file[$i]['company_id'];
                        $file_latitude = $addresses_file[$i]['new_lat'];
                        $file_longitude = $addresses_file[$i]['new_long'];

                        foreach($addresses_file as $y){

                            if($company_id == $y['company_id']){

                                $lat = $y['new_lat'];
                                $long = $y['new_long'];

                            }else{

                                $lat = $additionals[$company_id]['geo_lat'];
                                $long = $additionals[$company_id]['geo_long'];

                            }

                        }
```